# MVC Core Authorization

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization

I am using MVC Core for a website where I have the following issue to sort out.

Lets say that I have two groups GroupA and GroupB and these groups have some Entities. An entity either belongs to GroupA or GroupB - but not both at the same time. In order to protect updating of these entities, I have defined the following policy:

```
AuthorizationOptions.AddPolicy("UpdateEntityInGroupAPolicy", policy =>
{
    policy.RequireClaim("ClaimThatAllowsUpdatingEntityInGroupA");
});
```

This policy would make sure that users, who want to update an entity in GroupA has the claim ClaimThatAllowsUpdatingEntityInGroupA. A similar policy can be created for GroupB with claim ClaimThatAllowsUpdatingEntityInGroupB.

Further more, lets assume that GroupA has an entity with id 5 and GroupB has an entity with id 10. If a given user (who has the claim ClaimThatAllowsUpdatingEntityInGroupA, but not the claim ClaimThatAllowsUpdatingEntityInGroupB) is updating entity with id 5 at url:

http://example.com/entity/5/update

How do I now make sure that the user does not just change 5 in the url to 10 and actually update the other entity with id 10 in GroupB?

I hope I am clear with the question and thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `Authorize` attribute, you can't do this because Authorization Filter isn't aware of your entity. So, for your case [Resource Based Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased) seems right way to go.

First assuming your entity is like:

```
public class YourEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

To implement Resource Based Authorization

Create a requirement:

```
public class UpdateRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}
```

Create an authorization handler for requirement and entity

```
public class YourEntityAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<UpdateRequirement, YourEntity>
   {
       public override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                                   UpdateRequirement requirement,
                                                   YourEntity resource)
       {
           if(resource.Group == "GroupA" &&
              context.User.HasClaim("ClaimThatAllowsUpdatingEntityInGroupA"))
           {
               context.Succeed(requirement);
           }
           else if(resource.Group == "GroupB" &&
              context.User.HasClaim("ClaimThatAllowsUpdatingEntityInGroupB"))
           {
               context.Succeed(requirement);
           }
           return Task.CompletedTask;
       }
   }
```

Finally use it in your controller logic:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromServices]IAuthorizationService authorizationService, int id)
    {
        var entity= _entityRepository.Get(id);

        if (entity == null)
        {
            return new NotFoundResult();
        }

        if (await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, entity, new UpdateRequirement()))
        {
            return View(entity);
        }
        else
        {
            return new ChallengeResult();
        }
    }
```

Also see @blowdart's [example](https://github.com/blowdart/AspNetAuthorizationWorkshop/tree/master/src/Step_7_Resource_Based_Requirements)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I could also read the same approach else where like [this excellent page here](http://andrewlock.net/resource-specific-authorisation-in-asp-net-core/). I think thats the way to go. thanks :)